# Can't map mounted Linux folder

Tags: centos, network-drive, mount-point

I shared two folders via NFS on Windows and on CentOS server, then I mounted these two folders to mount point (\mnt\mymount).

Now I can't map creted mounted point on my Windows Server 2012 R2. I used  standard Map option for Network drives on Windows. I used string like \centosLexQA1\mnt\mymount in Map wizard.
I can successfully ping CentOS server from my Windows Server 2012 R2 and was able to map Linux share which was mounted to \mnt\mymount.

Could someone please help to resolve the issue?

Thank you in advance,
Anna